# Custom Adapter Where to inflate

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I have seen multiple code, where On one hand some inflate in constructor and assign to global variable ,on the other hand ,others inflate in getView() method .

So how the performance changes ,which way is better ?

In first option we have global variable but in second option it will inflate every time getView() called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ViewHolder** Pattern is the best way to implement list view in android. inflate the view for entire device screen and recycle element.